# Linq include with where clause

Tags: linq, include, where-clause

Hey so I've got the situation where I'm pulling a client back from the database and including all the case studies with it by way of an include

```
return (from c in db.Clients.Include("CaseStudies")
        where c.Id == clientId
        select c).First();
```

but what I want to do now is and a where clause on the included casestudies so that it only returns the case studies where deleted = false

sort of like this

```
return (from c in db.Clients.Include("CaseStudies")
        where c.Id == clientId
        && c.CaseStudy.Deleted == false
        select c).First();
```

But this doesn't work :( any ideas

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? In what way? What do you see?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it throw an exception, does it simply not return the results you expect? Is Deleted a boolean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conditional includes are not supported out-of-the-box in EF v1.0. But Alex James has a bit hacky workaround for that explained well here: http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/10/13/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include.aspx

```
 var dbquery =
   from c in db.Clients
   where c.Id == clientID
   select new {
      client = c, 
      caseStudies = from cs in c.CaseStudy
                where cs.Deleted==false
                select cs
   };

return dbquery
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(c => c.client);
```

Also, I haven't succeeded to make this workaround work with many-to-many relationships.

Comment: The better answer is query on `CaseStudies`, including `Client`, then `Select` Client, slap `.Distinct().ToList()`, and voila! `Client.CaseStudies` will be populated automatically through Navigation properties.

Comment: I think it also worth to mention that AsNoTracking will prevent EF from doing relationship fix-up magic (e.g. `from c in db.Clients.AsNoTracking()`)

Answer (score 1):

You can return a similar group of records this way, the GroupBy is going to make the enumeration different, but its not difficult.

```
CaseStudies.Include("Client")
           .Where(c => !c.Deleted && c.Client.ID == ClientID)
           .GroupBy(c => c.Client.ID);
```

Comment: This would've been my suggestion. `GroupBy` will work, but you could also just `Select` out the `Client`. So, you'd wind up with an `IEnumerable<Client>`. Also, slap a `.Distinct()` onto the end (EF knows what makes a Client distinct so you don't need a special `IEqualityComparer<Client>`). `Client.CaseStudies` will be populated on each because of Navigation Properties.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to perform a query on your results, like this:

```
var results = (from c in db.Clients.Include("CaseStudies")
               where c.Id == clientId
               select c).First();

results.CaseStudies = (from c in results.CaseStudies
                       where c.Deleted == false
                       select c).ToList();
```

Or of course you can use a lambda expression:

```
var results = db.Clients
                .Include(c => c.CaseStudies)
                .Where(c => c.ID == clientId).First();

results.CaseStudies = results.CaseStudies.Where(c => !c.Deleted).ToList();
```