# LINQ complex query navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a problem here with getting data from my database with LINQ

I have two tables `Team` and `TeamMember`, which are related by *1-N* relationship.
I am using Entity Framework and I have one entity for each of the tables with a property for each column. Also in the Team entity there is a `TeamMember` navigation property as result of this relationship.

I want to do a query where I can get all my Team's with their Team Members.

```
result = (from t in this.context.Teams
          orderby t.Name
          select t)
         .Include("TeamMembers")
```

That works fine. I get a collection of Team Entities with the `Team.TeamMember` property populated with the data of the member of each team.

The problem is when I want to do a more complex query like filtering the query for the TeamMembers.

For example, both tables have a column `EndDateTime`. If I want to get all the team and team members which are not ended (their end date time is not null) I don't know how to do it.

With this query I will filter just the teams, but not the team members.

```
result = (from t in this.context.Teams
          where t.EndDateTime == null
          orderby t.Name
          select t)
         .Include("TeamMembers")
         .ToList();
```

Any idea?

I kind of "solve" it doing the filter of the member after the query, to the collection. Like this:

```
//Filter out the End dated care coordiantors
var careCoordinatorsToDelete = new List<CareCoordinator>();
foreach (var team in result)
{
    careCoordinatorsToDelete.Clear();

    foreach (var careCoordinator in team.CareCoordinators)
    {
        if (careCoordinator.EndDateTime != null)
            careCoordinatorsToDelete.Add(careCoordinator);
    }

    foreach (var toDelete in careCoordinatorsToDelete)
    {
        team.CareCoordinators.Remove(toDelete);
    }
}
```

But I don't think this is a good solution at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [conditional include in linq to entities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085462/conditional-include-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: +1 This is a great question and one of the least obvious things to do with EF, but it is a duplicate. I think there are a few other duplicates as well.

Comment: another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680863/linq-include-with-where-clause

Answer (score 1):

As I've pointed out, I think this is a duplicate. But summarising the answers, you simply need to include the `Where` clause on the child as part of the `Select` statement (by using it as part of an anonymous type), enumerate the query, and then retrieve the objects you want.

Because you've selected the `TeamMembers` that you want into another property they will be retrieved from the database and constructed in your object graph.

```
result = (from t in this.context.Teams
          where t.EndDateTime == null
          orderby t.Name
          select new 
          { 
              Team = t,
              Members = t.TeamMembers.Where(tm => tm.EndDateTime == null)
          })
         .ToList()
         .Select(anon => anon.Team)
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Hey. I've tried that but it doesn't work! Could it be because I have Lazy loading deactivated?

Comment: @Asier - .ToList() forces query execution - thus the example is eager loading, not lazy loading...

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
var result = this.context.Teams.Where(t=>t.EndDateTime==null).Select(t=>
new { Name = t.Name,
             PropertyX = t.PropertyX... //pull any other needed team properties.
             CareCoordinators = t.CareCoordinators.Where(c=>c.EndDateTime==null)
}).ToList();
```

this returns a list of anonymous objects.