# How do I use a .Where() condition with a .Include()?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

This should be straightforward but I'm not making any progress on this issue. I want to write a LINQ statement that returns a person matching a given ID and include a set of visits. That I can do. Now, I need to include only active visits, that is include the visit only if the IsActive flag is true. My query is included below. What am I doing wrong?

```
var inmate = this.db.Inmates.Where(p => p.Id == id).Include(p => p.Visits.Where(v => v.IsActive)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Update #1 - I also tried this statement:

```
var inmate = this.db.Inmates.Include(p => p.Visits).Where(p => p.Id == id && p.Visits.Any(v => v.IsActive)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Have you seen this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680863/linq-include-with-where-clause?

Comment: I believe you are trying to do a conditional eager loading where by when you access inmateObject.Visits you only want the list of Active visits. This is already discussed over here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718400/conditional-eager-loading

Comment: @prashantht I agree. I really don't think there is any way to do this other than how they suggested in your link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var inmate = this.db.Inmates.Where(i => i.Visits.Any(x => x.IsActive))
```

Note: that the code assumes that the `IEnumerable<Visits>` is a property of an `Inmate` object.